# How to create rounded DataGrid top corners in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want exactly like this image? I could't find any answer. Could any one give me any suggestion or peace of xaml code. 
 [this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzvXV.jpg)

Comment: Hello, I think you could place the Datagrid inside a Border and set it's corner radius property.

Comment: Like many controls, the datagrid control template uses a border as the parent container. Copy the default, add corner radius to that and use that new template on your datagrid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates